# Pygame knowing when shift+other key is pressed

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I am trying to create a program similar to Microsoft word, only heavily simplified. I need to be able to know when shift+(any key) is pressed, and display the proper value for what was pressed (changed from just the normal key by the shift).

Currently, my best method is simply to find if a shift key is pressed, then whenever another key is pressed altering the number output from the pressed key to a new value that I can call chr() to change it into the shifted value for that key.

```
import pygame as py
import sys

py.init()

screen = py.display.set_mode((400,400))

clock = py.time.Clock()

font = py.font.match_font('Ariel')


def display_text(font,text,size,color,x,y):
    #just a way to display the text to the screen
    fontS = py.font.Font(font,size)
    rendering = fontS.render(text,True,color)
    text_rect = rendering.get_rect()
    text_rect.topleft = (x,y)
    screen.blit(rendering,text_rect)


going = True
display = ''

while going:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            py.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:

            #event keys from 32-126 are the ones that actually have a
            #character that you would type (ie that will prevent a SHIFT
            #from being displayed

            if event.key in range(32,127):

                pressedKeys = py.key.get_pressed()
                #find if a shift key is pressed
                if pressedKeys[py.K_RSHIFT] or pressedKeys[py.K_LSHIFT]:

                    #all below is handling for changing what the event key
                    #was to what it should be for when shift is pressed

                    if event.key in range(97,123):
                        event.key -= 32

                    if event.key in range(51,54):
                        event.key -= 16

                    if event.key == 50:
                        event.key = 64

                    if event.key == 49:
                        event.key = 33

                    if event.key == 54:
                        event.key = 94

                    if event.key == 55:
                        event.key = 38

                    if event.key == 56:
                        event.key = 42

                    if event.key == 57:
                        event.key -= 17

                display = chr(event.key)#change the number from event.key
                                        #into text

    display_text(font,display,40,(255,255,255),100,100)
    py.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The problem is that there are a bunch of different keys, and the number of statements needed to handle them all would be annoying to type out and just too long. Every character, such as . changing to > when shift is pressed all have to be accounted for.

Is there any way to detect when the shift key is pressed and automatically update what the output would be then? Is there another library that can do that? Or will I have to continue with my current method of changing the output depending on if shift was pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the events for 'a' and 'A' while both have the `key` 97, you can use either the `unicode` (if strictly printable characters) or `mod` attribute to tell the difference.

`<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 0, 'window': None, 'key': 97, 'unicode': u'a', 'mod': 0})>`

`<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 0, 'window': None, 'key': 97, 'unicode': u'A', 'mod': 1})>`

Note: the `mod` is different for `shift` and `caps lock` characters event though the `unicode` will be the same.

Comment: how are you able to see the entire event like that?

Comment: also, a simple way to solve my problem using your answer is simply calling event.unicode instead of event.key. That made it so much easier, and the mod isn't needed for what I used.

Comment: @YarnSaw I was just using `print` on the pygame event

Answer (score 2):

```
src = r"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;\'zxcvbnm,./"
dest = r'~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?'
ch = chr(event.key)
pressed = py.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[py.K_RSHIFT] or pressed[py.K_LSHIFT] and ch in src:
    ch = dest[src.index(ch)]
```

Comment: What does the prefix r do before the list of characters?

Comment: It makes it so that the "\" character doesn't need to be escaped.  That is, it is treated as an ordinary character.  I found an error in the code thanks to this review, and I've corrected it.